# Filter Bound Gridview to Drop Down

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've seen a couple example of how to do this by placing all the code in the aspx file, but I'm trying to do it from the code-behind. Here's what I have in the code behind:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
        conn.Open()
        Dim dtAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM table " & _
                                     "" _
                                    , conn)

        dtAdapter.SelectCommand = command
        dtAdapter.Fill(dt)
        conn.Close()
    End Using


    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

I'm open to any solutions, but I would prefer to do it in the code-behind if possible since thats how the rest of app is. I dont need to necessarily use a gridview just display some tabular data, so whatever works is fine. Im trying to avoid manually constructing sql strings. Any thoughts?

Comment: ive edited, is it more clear now?

Comment: If you really want to avoid constructing sql strings, you can use an ORM like [LINQ-to-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).  Otherwise, for one GridView and one DropDownList on one page, what's the big deal about adding a single `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the question. If you don't kno how to filter the records in your query, use the `Where` clause with a parameter:

```
Dim dt = New DataTable()
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field1 LIKE ?"
    Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(queryString, conn)
    command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Char, 3).Value = "a%"
    Using da = New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
        ' you don't need to open/close a connection if you use DataAdapter.Fill
        da.Fill(dt)
    End Using
End Using
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

- [DataAdapter Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)